# Trouble producing apk from react native project?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build the apk for this project https://github.com/react-native-material-design/demo-app, and when I run `./gradlew assembleRelease`
 from the android directory I get `Cannot evaluate module react-native-android-statusbar : Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

here is my `settings.gradle` file https://pastebin.com/YMiKkuw1
The output when running it with --stack-trace: https://pastebin.com/8UGs2zvT

*Edit*

tried `npm uninstall react-native-android-statusbar --save` 
and then re-install using `npm install react-native-android-statusbar --save`
the error changed, but I'm not experienced enough to solve it, here is the output of `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` :https://pastebin.com/AsEG6fcB

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove react-native-android-statusbar using `npm uninstall react-native-android-statusbar --save` 
After try re-install that using `npm install react-native-android-statusbar --save`
Link library using `npm link react-native-android-statusbar` 
Genarate unsigned apk using this script

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: tried what you said (here is the output: https://pastebin.com/gpqzg5b9)
I also tried re-running the same command I done before, the error message changed (check the update of the question please)

Comment: @ErnestDujo Try to delete **android/build**  folder from your project and again generate apk using above mentioned script

Comment: there is no android/build folder (tree of android: https://pastebin.com/71hXvzNk)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with project directory mentioned in status bar library is wrong.

```
project(':react-native-android-statusbar').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react-native-android-statusbar')
```

It should be **rootProject.projectDir** instead of **settingsDir**

```
project(':react-native-android-statusbar').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-android-statusbar')
```